# Repopulate a combobox itemlist without affecting what is currently written inside the combobox?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

How can I repopulate a combobox itemlist without affecting what is currently written inside the combobox?

I currently have code that looks kind of like:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim selText As String
    selText = ComboBox1.selText

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        ComboBox1.RemoveItem (0)
    Next i

    v = Call CreateList()
    For i = 0 to Ubound(v)
        ComboBox1.AddItem v(i)
    Next v
    If selText <> "" Then ComboBox1.Text = selText
End Sub
```

I haven't worked with comboboxes before so there are probably better methods. The code above has several problems

- It changes the selected value of the combobox (before attempting to restore it)
- It triggers the Combobox1_change event
- There are loops that I think might be unnecessary. Is is possible to remove all items without looping and adding multiple items without looping. The items to be added are created from a string that has comma separated values.

I would really appreciate help

Answer (score 2):

> There are loops that I think might be unnecessary. Is is possible to remove all items without looping and adding multiple items without looping.

`ComboBox1.Clear` will remove all items without looping. For adding you can use `.List` after you create the loop to add items to the ComboBox.

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim MyAr(1 To 5)

    For i = 1 To 5
        MyAr(i) = i
    Next i

    ComboBox1.List = MyAr
End Sub
```

> It triggers the Combobox1_change event

To prevent the `Combobox1_change event`, you will have to use a boolean variable like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578093/vba-userform-with-multiples-textboxes-in-infinite-calculation-loop#comment49226676_30578093)

> It changes the selected value of the combobox (before attempting to restore it)

Store the value in a variable and then reset the combobox value if that value is part of the dropdown list

Comment: In regards to the event firing. could you not just use application.enablevents=false ?

Comment: @99moorem No - it doesn't affect the events for controls. (well, it does affect some if the control is on a worksheet, but those events really belong to the container, not the control)

Comment: @Rory Hmm learn something new every day, have to play around with it when I get time.